# I want to add a caption to this table, and the (\caption) is not working. I had two errors 1.Undefined control sequence. 2. \caption outside float

Tags: captions, tabularx

```
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C||C||C|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Table 1: State of The ART Schemes With Intelligent Surfaces}\\
\hline\hline
 Scheme & Architecture & Functionality \\
\hline
Intelligent wall & Active frequency selective surfaces with PIN diodes & Fully transparent reflecting surfaces\\
Spatial microwave modulators & Binary phase state tunable meta-surfaces & Shaping complex microwave fields\\
Coding meta-materials & Meta-surfaces with binary elements (0 or $\pi$ phases) & Reconfigurable scattering patterns\\
Programmable meta-surface & Meta-surfaces with PIN diode-equipped cells & Reconfigurable phase, polarization, and scattering\\
Reconfigurable reflect-arrays & Reflect-arrays with tunable (varactor-tuned) resonators & Adjustable reflection phase\\
Large intelligent surface & Active contiguous surface for transmission and reception & Gains compared to massive MIMO   \\
Software-controlled hypersurface & Meta-surfaces equipped with IoT gateways & Wave absorption, polarization, and steering\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: if something isn't working please show an example document  and show the error you got. `\caption` does not need a `tabular` (or `tabularx`) so the code shown does not help solve your problem, it does need to be inside a `table` environment`.

Comment: LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.63 \end{tabularx}
                   
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Comment: also .... Undefined control sequence. The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means. ■ Also, [edit] the question to add the information, not post in a comment.

Comment: You have not provided a test document that produces the error and have not shown the part of the error message that says which command is not defined, so it is impossible to help unless you edit your question to have some information.

Comment: `LaTeX Error: \caption outside float. `  means as I guessed in the first coment that you used `\caption` without this being inside `\begin{table} .. \end{table}`

Answer (score 1):

The `\caption` (of a tabular) should be inside the environment `table`.

The package `caption` helps to setup the format of the caption, but it is not needed to use the command `\caption`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption} % added 

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

    \noindent
    \begin{table}% added <<<<<<<<<
        \setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
        \caption{State of The ART Schemes With Intelligent Surfaces}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|C||C||C|} 
%       \hline
%       \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Table 1: State of The ART Schemes With Intelligent Surfaces}\\
%       \hline
        \hline
        Scheme & Architecture & Functionality \\
        \hline
        Intelligent wall & Active frequency selective surfaces with PIN diodes & Fully transparent reflecting surfaces\\
        Spatial microwave modulators & Binary phase state tunable meta-surfaces & Shaping complex microwave fields\\
        Coding meta-materials & Meta-surfaces with binary elements (0 or $\pi$ phases) & Reconfigurable scattering patterns\\
        Programmable meta-surface & Meta-surfaces with PIN diode-equipped cells & Reconfigurable phase, polarization, and scattering\\
        Reconfigurable reflect-arrays & Reflect-arrays with tunable (varactor-tuned) resonators & Adjustable reflection phase\\
        Large intelligent surface & Active contiguous surface for transmission and reception & Gains compared to massive MIMO   \\
        Software-controlled hypersurface & Meta-surfaces equipped with IoT gateways & Wave absorption, polarization, and steering\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```